# API has \ in data that needs to print to webpage

Tags: angular, api

I trying to print out the inclusions from an API to the webpage. but the \ makes it print the html as text and not as html elements.

API section:

```
inclusions: "\"<ul>\\r\\n<li>2 nights accommodation in a standard suite room<\\/li>   <li>Breakfast, lunch and dinner daily<\\/li><li>2 Game drive daily<\\/li><li>Community Levy<\\/li><li>Champagne and chocolates  |  truffles on arrival<\\/li><li>Romantic turndown<\\/li><\\/ul>\""
```

in my angular component i have :

```
export class PackageDetailComponent implements OnInit {

public package:any = {} ;
packageId;
packageList:any = {};
inclusion:any = {};


constructor(private _packageService: PackageService, 
            private route:ActivatedRoute) { 

}


getPackage(){
 this.packageList = this._packageService.packageData.getValue().product;
 this.package = this.packageList.find(p=>p.package_id === this.packageId);
 this.inclusion = this.package.inclusions;
}
```

In my HTML i tried both these methods:

```
<div class="test">{{package.inclusions}}</div>
<div class="includes" [innerHTML]=inclusion></div>
```

this renders it in the browser as:

```
"<ul>\r\n<li>5 Nights accommodation on board the MSC Musica in an inside cabin<\/li><li>All meals<\/li><li>All on-board entertainment included<\/li><li>Mandatory port, service and insurance charges<\/li><\/ul>"
"

    \r\n
    5 Nights accommodation on board the MSC Musica in an inside cabin<\/li>
    All meals<\/li>
    All on-board entertainment included<\/li>
    Mandatory port, service and insurance charges<\/li><\/ul>"
```

i stead of a proper list item. What am i missing here?

Comment: Looks like double encoding. Try `this.inclusion = JSON.parse(this.package.inclusions);`

Comment: thank you very much @HereticMonkey that work great. could you explain what it actually does so i can understand?

Comment: Basically, someone encoded the string as JSON and set the value of `inclusions` to that encoded string. Then, the already-encoded JSON was again encoded and sent to you. Angular decoded the outer encoding automatically. However, you have to manually decode the `inclusions` property. If you can discuss this with the people who are sending you the data, it may be a bug on their end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backslashes in JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140517/backslashes-in-json-string)