# Publish platform event with a rich text field that contains JSON

Tags: json, salesforce, salesforce-communities

[Sample JSON Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZkd4.png)

Platform events let's us add fields and then send data in those. My requirement is to send multiple contacts in each message that is published via platform events. I have created a list of wrapper class and then used JSON.serialize to convert it to a JSON string format. This is enabling me to create a JSON with multiple contact records. In the platform event I have a rich text field which is then storing the value of the JSON string formed. The issue observed is that the JSON inside the Rich text field of Platform event has backslash in it for every json key and value string quotation.

Could you help as to how me can remove this backslash and basically be able to send JSON within platform event fields.

Comment: may be backslash is there for reason. can you update question or attach snapshot for a this file?

Comment: @NadeemTaj Hi Nadeem, I have attached the snapshot. So the JSON inside the payload cannot be deserialized immediately by third party due to the backslash and hence the problem.

Comment: JSON.parse function is in your script? This is good document for you to start with. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140517/backslashes-in-json-string

Comment: We are just publishing the message, a third party is supposed to consume it and they cannot with the backslash. I believe that since I am using JSON.serialize to store it in the Long text area field of platform event and then during publish salesforce internally tries to convert the message into JSON, a double serialization is happening on the internal JSON payload and hence the backslash is appearing. I want to remove these backslashes before it is published. So parse in my case wouldn't be useful.